# Docker volumes-from not working when launching container with -H host flat

Tags: linux, docker

Looking at shipyard, I noticed that the deploy container launches containers on the host ( redis, router, database, load balancer, shipyard)
This is done by using the -H flag.

So I decided to try this to deploy my apps as this would make deployment tons easier ( versus systemd, init.d ).
I was able to get about 70% there, but the thing that broke was **--volumes-from** tag.

The container starts, but the volume it's mounting to is empty.  I have a simple example posted here.

http://goo.gl/a558XL

If you run these commands on host. it works fine.

```
on_host$ docker run --name data joshuacalloway/data
on_host$ docker run --volumes-from data ubuntu cat /data/hello.txt
```

However if you do this in a container. It is broken.

```
on_host$ docker run -it --entrypoint=/bin/bash -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock joshuacalloway/deploy -s
in_container:/# docker ps -----> this shows docker processes on the host
in_container:/# docker rm data ---> this removes docker container data that was created above
in_container:/# docker run --name data joshuacalloway/data
in_container:/# docker run --volumes-from data ubuntu cat /data/hello.txt
```